# Are the fixed width integer types guaranteed to be typedefs for the standard built in types?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Are the types from `<cstdint>` (like e.g. `int16_t`, `uint_fast64_t`, `int_least8_t`) guaranteed to be `typedef`s for one of the built in types like `short`, `unsigned long` etc.?

Or is an implementation allowed to use types that are non of the usual built in ones to implement the fixed width types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are specified by the C standard (and incorporated by reference by the C++ standard), which requires each to be a typedef for a *signed integer type* or *unsigned integer type*, as the case may be.

*signed integer type* is in turn defined by the core language to consist of the *standard signed integer types* (which are `signed char`, `short int`, `int`, `long int` and `long long int`) and any implementation-defined *extended signed integer types*.

Similarly, *unsigned integer type* is defined by the core language to consist of the *standard unsigned integer types* (which are `unsigned char`, `unsigned short int`, `unsigned int`, `unsigned long int` and `unsigned long long int`) and any implementation-defined *extended unsigned integer types* corresponding to the extended signed integer types.

In short, each of those typedefs may be one of the usual built-in types or an implementation-defined extended integer type. Most compilers do not support extended integer types, so on those compilers they must be built-in types.

Answer (score 4):

No, at least not for types `intN_t`. These types are guaranteed to have two’s complement representation (as per C99 7.18.1.1 which C++11 and C++14 reference). And standard integer types don't have to be two's complement.

C11 also has important change over C99 (which is actually just bugfix), emphasizing the point above:

7.20.1.1/3:

> However, if an implementation provides integer types with
>   widths of 8, 16, 32, or 64 bits, no padding bits, **and (for the signed types) that have a
>   two’s complement representation**, it shall define the corresponding typedef names.

Comment: But that does not proof that an implementation that does not use two's complement is actually allowed to provide those optional types (in C++), doesn't it?

Comment: @BaummitAugen the implementation is not prohibited from providing these optional types in any case, and in case if the standard types are not two's complement, `intN_t` types will certainly not be typedefs for standard types.

Answer (score 2):

I have a draft version of the C99 spec in front of me and a draft of the C++14 spec as well. Since these are drafts, this information might be incorrect, but I believe that the wording is the same in the final version.

In the C++14 spec, §18.4.1 has this to say about `<cstdint>`:

```
namespace std {
   typedef signed-integer-type int8_t; // optional
   typedef signed-integer-type int16_t; // optional
   typedef signed-integer-type int32_t; // optional
   typedef signed-integer-type int64_t; // optional

   [ etc. ]
}
```

It then says

> The header defines all functions, types, and macros the same as 7.18 in the C standard.

I went to the draft C99 standard, §7.18, and saw nothing that required the types defined to actually be aliases for built-in types like `int`, `long int`, etc. It just said that if these types exist, they have to meet certain constraints about their ranges, sizes, and memory layouts.

Overall, I strongly suspect that the answer is "no," but if I'm mistaken, I'm interested to see where I misread the spec. :-)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Seems to be the strongest proof here, I hope it is also correct (and it is as far as I can see). I will check again tomorrow, if some language lawyer comes along to disprove your answer.

Answer (score 1):

From the C++ standard: "There may also be implementation-defined extended signed integer types. The standard and extended signed integer types are collectively called signed integer types. ". (I think there is a similar line about extended unsigned integer types) Nothing is said how you would use these extended integer types, they are obviously non-portable and implementation defined.

However, int16_t etc. can be typedefs for extended integer types.

Comment: Extended integer types must still obey all the core language rules for integer types.

Comment: That does not state if those extended types are allowed to be used to implement the types from `<cstdint>`.

Comment: @BaummitAugen It does. The types in `<cstdint>` are required to be signed or unsigned integer types, and gnasher729's quote shows how the standard defines "signed integer type". Showing that "signed integer type" allows for "extended signed integer type" answers your question, does it not?

Comment: @hvd Well we  might have an answer if we combine your comment (plus some standard quote) and the above answer. :)

Comment: @BaummitAugen I see your point, the answer could be clearer. I'm perfectly okay with it if gnasher729 wants to incorporate my comment into the answer, preferably also elaborating a bit more. :)