# C++: Disadvatages of using std::uint_fastn_t

Tags: c++, fixed-width

So I stumbled upon [When should I use the C++ fixed-width integer types and how do they impact performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57141453/when-should-i-use-the-c-fixed-width-integer-types-and-how-do-they-impact-perfo) and [Should I use cstdint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6144682/should-i-use-cstdint) where the advantages and disadvantages of fixed width integer types as defined in `<cstdint>` are listed.

I kinda do like to encode the intended range of a variable into its type but I also don't want to enforce the CPU to do extra operations just to use a `uint16_t` instead of a plain `int` when I am not strictly required to have a variable holding exactly 16 bits.

I also read about types like `std::uint_fast16_t` and so on. From my understanding using this type should ensure that I am guaranteed to be able to store a 16-bit number in that variable but I should never have to pay any runtime penality for using this type since on every architecture where e.g. `uint32_t` would be faster, that would be used automatically for me.

This leaves me with the question: Aside from the case that I really need a variable of exact bit width, are there any disadvantages of using `std::uint_fast16_t` instead of say `unsigned int`?

---

EDIT: This is of course assuming that memory consumption is not an issue. If it was, I would use `std::uint_least16_t` instead.

Comment: "  should never have to pay any runtime penality for using this type" is more like " usually   not have to pay any runtime penalty for using this type"

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica How is that? Would that then be a bug in the C++ implementation on that particular machine or something else?

Comment: "_... there any disadvantages..."_ that you might use twice the expected space when `uint32_t` is faster.

Comment: @RichardCritten Yep fair point - Let me clarify that in the question...

Comment: TL;DR from the duplicate: `uint_fast16_t` may not be exactly 16 bits big. It will be the 'fastest' type with *at least* 16 bits.

Comment: @AdrianMole This question already explains the difference between the two. I don't think the duplicate is accurate. This question is asking if there are other disadvantages to using the `fast` type other than the extra size.

Comment: @AdrianMole I also think that the linked question does not answer my question.

Comment: A difference does not have to be a disadvantage. One car is red the other is yellow. That's a difference but not necessarily a disadvatage

Comment: OK - I've reopened after the convincing weight of arguments. :-)

Comment: @AdrianMole Questions about pros/cons of one type versus another in C/C++ is tricky, so I appreciate your pro/con thoughts about duplication.  We could have a single question about the many types versus the other many types.  So many things to consider and thus too broad  Some issues apply to specific cases, some do not.  Short making a treatise  "what every programmer needs to know about type selection".  Perhaps we need a Q&A to serve as a table of contents linking to the specific cases?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> are there any disadvantages of using `std::uint_fast16_t` instead of say `unsigned int`.

One disadvantage: uncertain type due do the usual promotions.  Does `uint16_fast_t` convert to a *signed* or *unsigned*?

```
uint_fast16_t fa = 1;
unsigned un = 1;
int i;

fa some_operator i --> may result in an `int` or `uint_fast16_t`
un some_operator i --> result is unsigned.
```

The ambiguity may negatively affect more complicated equations and behavior on overflow.

---

IMO, `uint16_fast_t` only useful in narrow controlled code, not for a general performance improvement.  Be careful of [Is premature optimization really the root of all evil?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil).

Many factors affect this conclusion, yet generally for performance, *usually* best to go for clarity and type `unsigned`.

Comment: Just to clarify: When you write "Usually best to go for clarity and unsigned." do you mean `unsigned int` or `uint16_t` (to stick with my example)?

Comment: @Raven The _type_: `unsigned`.

Comment: @Raven I did not go into `uint_fastn_t` and focussed on `uint_fast16_t`.  A short-coming of `uint_fastn_t` vs. `unsigned` when `n > 16` is that `unsigned` maybe of sufficient range.

Comment: @Raven IMO, `uint_fastn_t` should be specified to be no narrower than `unsigned` to avoid the disadvantage answered above.  I find `uint_fastn_t` too problematic for portable code.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification :)